# MongoDB nested lookup with 3 levels

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, lookup

I need to retrieve the entire single object hierarchy from the database as a JSON. Actually, the proposal about any other solution to achieve this result would be highly appreciated. I decided to use MongoDB with its `$lookup` support.

So I have three collections:

**party**

```
{ "_id" : "2", "name" : "party2" }
{ "_id" : "5", "name" : "party5" }
{ "_id" : "4", "name" : "party4" }
{ "_id" : "1", "name" : "party1" }
{ "_id" : "3", "name" : "party3" }
```

**address**

```
{ "_id" : "a3", "street" : "Address3", "party_id" : "2" }
{ "_id" : "a6", "street" : "Address6", "party_id" : "5" }
{ "_id" : "a1", "street" : "Address1", "party_id" : "1" }
{ "_id" : "a5", "street" : "Address5", "party_id" : "5" }
{ "_id" : "a2", "street" : "Address2", "party_id" : "1" }
{ "_id" : "a4", "street" : "Address4", "party_id" : "3" }
```

**addressComment**

```
{ "_id" : "ac2", "address_id" : "a1", "comment" : "Comment2" }
{ "_id" : "ac1", "address_id" : "a1", "comment" : "Comment1" }
{ "_id" : "ac5", "address_id" : "a5", "comment" : "Comment6" }
{ "_id" : "ac4", "address_id" : "a3", "comment" : "Comment4" }
{ "_id" : "ac3", "address_id" : "a2", "comment" : "Comment3" }
```

I need to retrieve all parties with all corresponding addresses and address comments as part of the record. My aggregation:

```
db.party.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "address",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "party_id",
        as: "address"
    }
},
{
    $unwind: "$address"
},
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "addressComment",
        localField: "address._id",
        foreignField: "address_id",
        as: "address.addressComment"
    }
}])
```

The result is pretty weird. Some records are ok. But Party with `_id: 4` is missing (there is no address for it). Also, there are two Party `_id: 1` in the result set (but with different addresses):

```
{
    "_id": "1",
    "name": "party1",
    "address": {
        "_id": "2",
        "street": "Address2",
        "party_id": "1",
        "addressComment": [{
            "_id": "3",
            "address_id": "2",
            "comment": "Comment3"
        }]
    }
}{
    "_id": "1",
    "name": "party1",
    "address": {
        "_id": "1",
        "street": "Address1",
        "party_id": "1",
        "addressComment": [{
            "_id": "1",
            "address_id": "1",
            "comment": "Comment1"
        },
        {
            "_id": "2",
            "address_id": "1",
            "comment": "Comment2"
        }]
    }
}{
    "_id": "3",
    "name": "party3",
    "address": {
        "_id": "4",
        "street": "Address4",
        "party_id": "3",
        "addressComment": []
    }
}{
    "_id": "5",
    "name": "party5",
    "address": {
        "_id": "5",
        "street": "Address5",
        "party_id": "5",
        "addressComment": [{
            "_id": "5",
            "address_id": "5",
            "comment": "Comment5"
        }]
    }
}{
    "_id": "2",
    "name": "party2",
    "address": {
        "_id": "3",
        "street": "Address3",
        "party_id": "2",
        "addressComment": [{
            "_id": "4",
            "address_id": "3",
            "comment": "Comment4"
        }]
    }
}
```

Please help me with this. I'm pretty new to MongoDB but I feel it can do what I need from it.

Comment: This may also be helpful for future devs: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#perform-multiple-joins-and-a-correlated-subquery-with--lookup

Answer (score 114, accepted):

The cause of your 'troubles' is the second aggregation stage -  `{ $unwind: "$address" }`. It removes record for party with `_id: 4` (because its address array is empty, as you mention) and produces two records for parties `_id: 1` and `_id: 5` (because each of them has two addresses).

- To prevent removing of parties without addresses you should set `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` option of [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage to `true`.
- To prevent duplicating of parties for its different addresses you should add [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) aggregation stage to your pipeline. Also, use [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage with [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator to exclude empty address records in output.

```js
db.party.aggregate([{
  $lookup: {
    from: "address",
    localField: "_id",
    foreignField: "party_id",
    as: "address"
  }
}, {
  $unwind: {
    path: "$address",
    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
  }
}, {
  $lookup: {
    from: "addressComment",
    localField: "address._id",
    foreignField: "address_id",
    as: "address.addressComment",
  }
}, {
  $group: {
    _id : "$_id",
    name: { $first: "$name" },
    address: { $push: "$address" }
  }
}, {
  $project: {
    _id: 1,
    name: 1,
    address: {
      $filter: { input: "$address", as: "a", cond: { $ifNull: ["$$a._id", false] } }
    } 
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Tank you Shad! There is one little problem with record 4 though:
`{
 "_id": "4",
 "name": "party4",
 "address": [{
  "addressComment": []
 }]
}`
As you can see - address should be null but it is an empty record instead... Can we skip the address if its addressComment is empty? In other case this address will be considered a record.

Comment: Actually I see that provided solution works as expected according to the description of new "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" field for $unwind operation (since 3.2). Now we can skip the "$project" step and specify this "$unwind" instead of the simple one: `$unwind: {path: "$address",preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}`.I will accept your answer, thank you for a quick and clear response!

Comment: @Shad I have quite similar question. Here OP's code has only one property called `name` in `party` collection and hence you used `$first` to get it in `$group`. Suppose I have 10+ properties, then is there any way to automatically get all the properties without mentioning each of it individually?

Comment: How do we add a group clause for "addressComment" if there were different comments for the same address id? As mentioned this query works well for grouping at "address" level.

Answer (score 98):

With the mongodb **3.6** and above [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup) syntax it is quite simple to join nested fields without using [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/).

```
db.party.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "address",
    "let": { "partyId": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$party_id", "$$partyId"] }}},
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": "addressComment",
        "let": { "addressId": "$_id" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$address_id", "$$addressId"] }}}
        ],
        "as": "address"
      }}
    ],
    "as": "address"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$address" }
])
```

Comment: How would you access partyId in the inner pipeline if it were needed tho?

Comment: @Paulo By using `$$` sign

Comment: are you sure, I understand you can get addressId like so `$$addressId`

Comment: @Paulo please refer to [this link in the mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.4/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#std-label-aggregation-expressions)  for clarity

Comment: hi @Ashh, can you check my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70021771/mongodb-aggregation-select-only-same-value-from-array-inside-lookup

Comment: I'm wondering what executes first inside these lookups, is it a top-down approach like @shad answer? Or does it first execute the addressComent lookup?

Comment: @Paulo In this example it does the same, in lookup.let $field always refers to local object fields. So you can access partyid in inner lookup let:{"partyId":"$party_id"}