# Using lookup on Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, lookup, projection

I have three collections:

*Stories*:

```
{
    "idStory": "story-5ac97232b2ea82701e853d0b",
    "chapters": [
        { "idChapter": "chapter-5ac97274b2ea82701e853d11" },
        { "idChapter": "chapter-5ac97593c9c35a7079f85f8c" }
    ]
}
```

*Chapters*:

```
[
    {
        "idChapter": "chapter-5ac97274b2ea82701e853d11"
    },
    {
        "idChapter": "chapter-5ac97593c9c35a7079f85f8c",
        "images": [
            { "idImage": "image-5ac97593c9c35a7079f85f8c" },
            { "idImage": "image-5ac9f63f8bfb1b7b5bced68e" }
        ]
    }
]
```

*Images*:

```
[
    {
        "idImage": "image-5ac97593c9c35a7079f85f8c",
        "URI": "http://mypath1"
        "dateCreation": "12/12/1973"
    },
    {
        "idImage": "image-5ac9f63f8bfb1b7b5bced68e",
        "URI": "http://mypath2"
        "dateCreation": "12/12/1973"
    }
]
```

And I need this result:

```
{
    "idStory": "story-5ac97232b2ea82701e853d0b",
    "chapters": [
        { "idChapter": "chapter-5ac97274b2ea82701e853d11" }
        {
            "idChapter": "chapter-5ac97593c9c35a7079f85f8c"
            "images": [
                { "URI": "http://mypath1" },
                { "URI": "http://mypath2" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried with this stages:

1. `find` the *Story*;
2. `$lookup` for the related *Chapters*:

   ```
   '$lookup': {
       'from': 'chapters',
       'localField': 'idChapter',
       'foreignField': 'idChapter',
       'as': 'chapters'
   }
   ```
3. `$unwind` the *Chapters*:

   ```
   '$unwind': '$chapters'
   ```
4. `$lookup` for the related *Images*:

   ```
   '$lookup': {
       'from': 'images',
       'localField': 'chapters.idImage',
       'foreignField': 'idImage',
       'as': 'images'
   }
   ```
5. and finally `$project`:

   ```
   '$project': {
       'idStory': true,
       'chapters': {
           'idChapter': '$chapters.idChapter',
           'images': {
               'URI': '$images.URI'
           }
       }
   }
   ```

but this doesn't works: it always repeat the first element on the unwinded array.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `'localField': '$chapters'` is not even valid, let alone not being the correct path. You will get more help with an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which basically means "give people enough data to produce the result you expect".  So if you want to show a result with multiple chapters, then provide that data and everything actually related to it.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB nested lookup with 3 levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019713/mongodb-nested-lookup-with-3-levels)

Comment: @NeilLunn sorry, I've correct the error, but anyway this is absolutely my real datas.

Comment: I'm not doubting it's "real", just that the example is lacking data. Story has 2 chapters  and you provide "one". The provided chapter has two images, and you again provide only "one". Please include the rest of the data that relates back to the original "story". This makes the problem "reproducible" and by definition "solvable".