# How to write a self-join query up to 3 level nested array in mongoDB

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb

I have tried to get the 3 level or more nested array list using self-join in mongoDB.

Collection named `Book`:

```
_id    value         parent-Id
1     Chapter 1       0
2     Chapter 1.1     1
3     Chapter 1.2     1
4     Chapter 1.1.1   2
5     Chapter 1.1.2   2
6     Chapter 2       0
7     Chapter 2.1     6
```

Every "parent-Id" is the ID of the chapter given in the same table, if there is no parent then "parent-Id" will be `0`.

Now. I want that output structure should be like the following structure:

```
{
  "_id": "1",
    "chapter": "chater 1",
      "parent-Id": "0",
        "children": [
          {
            "_id": "2",
            "chapter": "chater 1.1",
            "parent-Id": "1",
            "children": [
              {
                "_id": "4",
                "chapter": "chater 1.1.1",
                "parent-Id": "2",
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "_id": "5",
                "chapter": "chater 1.1.2",
                "parent-Id": "2",
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "_id": "3",
            "chapter": "chater 1.2",
            "parent-Id": "1",
            "children": []

          }
        ]
}, {
  "_id": "5",
    "chapter": "chater 2",
      "parent-Id": "0",
        "children": [
          {
            "_id": "7",
            "chapter": "chater 2.1",
            "parent-Id": "5",
            "children": [   
}
```

```
chapter 1
  Chapter 1.1
    Chapter 1.1.1
    Chapter 1.1.2
  Chapter 1.2
Chapter 2
  Chapter 2.1
```

I am able to get 2 level structure but find cannot the solution for three level (i.e.  chapter 1.1.1).

For level 2, I have used :

```
db.Book.aggregate({
    $lookup: {
           from: "Book",
           localField: "_id",
           foreignField: "parent-Id",
           as: "children"
         }
},
         {$match: {
             "parentId" : 0
         }})
```

Comment: Please try below link :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019713/mongodb-nested-lookup-with-3-levels
Thanks

Comment: Please check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019713/mongodb-nested-lookup-with-3-levels
Thanks